# Wrong format of Year in Chart

Tags: google-earth-engine, date, chart, format

I am calculating the Annual mean NDVI from S2 data and trying to plot it. However, in the chart, the format of all years is not correctly presented. The 'year' values are presented as double. How I may force it to have the correct date format?

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/c5c9a6518584e41a2cf1b5793242b315

```
var Level2 = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level2");
var Sindh =Level2.filterMetadata('ADM1_NAME', 'equals', 'Sindh');
print (Sindh.size()); 
//Load Sentinel 2 image collection and calculate NDVI over the selected time-period
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
                  .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2022-01-01')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
                  .select(['B4','B8'])
                  .filterBounds(Sindh);
print (S2.size());

// function to calculate NDVI in S2

var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var NDVI = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
  .multiply(10000)
  .rename('NDVI')
  .copyProperties(image,['system:time_start']);
  return image.addBands(NDVI);
};


// Add NDVI to the image collection
var withNDVI = S2.map(addNDVI);
//print("NDVI collection", withNDVI.first());

var startyear = 2018;
var endyear = 2021;

// list years over which to obtain time series
var years = ee.List.sequence(startyear, endyear,1);

var byYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
    years.map(function(y) {
      return withNDVI
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
        .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
        .set('year', y);
    })
  );


print (byYear);


Map.centerObject(Sindh,6);
 
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:  byYear,
  band: 'NDVI_mean',
  regions: Sindh,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 5000,
  seriesProperty: 'ADM2_NAME',
  xProperty: 'year'
});
 
print(chart);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Earth Engine [`ui.Chart`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/charts_overview) module uses Google Charts. Google Charts allow you to format axis labels with the `hAxis.format` and `yAxis.format` properties. See examples of formatting strings in the [Configuration Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) section of the line chart docs.

In Earth Engine, you set style properties using the [`ui.Chart.setOptions`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ui-chart-setoptions) method. In your case, you can set the `hAxis.format` property to `'####'` to remove the decimal and comma.

For other chart styling tips, see the [Earth Engine chart styling page](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/charts_style).

```js
chart.setOptions({
  hAxis: {
    format: '####'
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.